# $L_1$ distance between re-normalized points

Tags: geometry, normed-spaces, vector-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in (0, \infty)^d$. Are there general relations between
$
\Vert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y} \Vert_1
$
and
$
\left\Vert 
\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_1}
-\frac{\mathbf{y}}{\Vert \mathbf{y}\Vert_1}
\right\Vert_1
$? E.g. one is upper-bounded by a constant times the other etc.

Comment: It seems to me that, for example, if both $\Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_1>1$ and $\Vert \mathbf{y}\Vert_1>1$, the $L_1$ distance between non-normalized points is larger than the $L_1$ distance between normalized points. If instead both $\Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_1<1$ and $\Vert \mathbf{y}\Vert_1<1$, the opposite is true. So that, apparently, no general relation exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assume wlog $||x||_1\leq||y||_1$. We have
\begin{equation}
||\frac{x}{||x||}-\frac{y}{||y||}||=\frac{1}{||x||}||x-\frac{||x||y}{||y||}||\\=\frac{1}{||x||}||x-y+(1-\frac{||x||}{||y||})y||\leq\frac{1}{||x||}||x-y||+(\frac{1}{||x||}-\frac{1}{||y||})||y||\\=\frac{1}{||x||}||x-y||+\frac{||y||}{||x||}-1
\end{equation}